# Implementation of getUTF8Length

Tags: javascript

I'm learning the source code of qrcode that implemented by javascript.
And I'm confused about the implementation of getUTF8Length.
Here is the source code:

```
function _getUTF8Length(sText) {
    var replacedText = encodeURI(sText).toString().replace(/\%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g, 'a');
    return replacedText.length + (replacedText.length != sText ? 3 : 0);
}
```

I wanna to know how to understand the REGEX and why add 3 to the length.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. In this case it is not clear what your question is. You want an expanded explanation of the REGEX?

Comment: thanks, i'm beginner of stackoverflow.I'm sorry that i missed the ask rule.I have changed my question.

Comment: Could you also add a link to the source code if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression will find all %00-%FF and convert them to "a"

I do not understand the statement

```
replacedText.length != sText
```

I would expect that to be

```
replacedText.length != sText.length
```

but I cannot explain why they would add 3

```js
function _getUTF8Length(sText) {
    console.log(encodeURI(sText))
    var replacedText = encodeURI(sText).toString().replace(/\%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g, 'a');
    console.log(replacedText)  
    return replacedText.length + (replacedText.length != sText ? 3 : 0);
}

// Assuming a text of ABCD CR double bytes
var text = "ABCD \n张加涛";
console.log(_getUTF8Length(text))
```

Comment: Thank you, worship you, i totally understand that now. It seems that i should think more.